# How to retrieve filtered multi-index table data?

Tags: eosjs, multi-index, rpc, api

I have a smart contract that has a multi-index table called reservations - account, time, date, entity. From the code I am trying to use get_table_rows to get all reservations related to a given account. The problem is, with the rpc call that I am using I get all possible reservations not only the ones that are related to a given user. So, my questions are:

- How can I achieve my goal in the most optimized way with the current implementation?
- Do I need a second index in the reservations table?
- If yes, would I be able to use it in the way I described above?

```
static async getAllReservationsByUser(reservationAccount) {
try {
  // const rpc = new JsonRpc('http://127.0.0.1:8888', { fetch });
  const resp = await rpc.get_table_rows({
    json: true,
    code: EOS_ACCOUNT, // contract who owns the table
    scope: EOS_ACCOUNT, // scope of the table
    table: 'reservations', // name of the table as specified by the contract 
    table_key: 'reservationAccount',
    // lower_bound: userName,
    limit: 100,
  });
  console.log('[getAllReservationsByUser]: response = ', resp);
  return resp.rows;
} catch (err) {
  console.log('[getAllReservationsByUser]: error = ', err);
}}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
static async getAllReservationsByUser(reservationAccount) {
try {
  // const rpc = new JsonRpc('http://127.0.0.1:8888', { fetch });
  const resp = await rpc.get_table_rows({
    json: true,
    code: EOS_ACCOUNT, // contract who owns the table
    scope: EOS_ACCOUNT, // scope of the table
    table: 'reservations', // name of the table as specified by the contract 
    lower_bound: userName,
    upper_bound: userName,
    limit: 100,
  });
  console.log('[getAllReservationsByUser]: response = ', resp);
  return resp.rows;
} catch (err) {
  console.log('[getAllReservationsByUser]: error = ', err);
}}
```

Comment: Could you provide some more info about why did you upvote it. What is wrong with the answer in order for me to correct it